# Can't login through POST

Tags: c#, authentication, post

Im working on `C# WinForms app`, that connects to web page, logs in and get some data.

I'm unsuccessfull with the login part - I've read dozens of articles here, but nothing works.

The page I'm trying to access is ASP.NET based. Besides that, I'm new in web development.

**Chunks of code from login page:**

```
<form action="/User/Login" id="LoginForm" method="post"><input id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" type="hidden" value="/">
    <td>
      <input id="login" name="login" style="width:150px;" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="pass" name="pass" style="width:150px;" type="password">
    </td>
```

**And submit:**

```
<span class="ButtonWrap">
    <a href="javascript:submit();" class="ButtonGreen">Login</a>
</span>
<input type="submit">
```

From all the articles I had read and try, I can connect to page and POST login data but the response is always the same - Im redirected login page.

**C# code from my program:**

```
var response = Http.Post("...desired web page...", new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection() {
    { "login", "loginData" },
    { "heslo", "passData" }
});
public static class Http
{
    public static byte[] Post(string uri, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection pairs)
    {
         byte[] response = null;
         using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
         {
             response = client.UploadValues(uri, "POST", pairs);
         }
         return response;
    }
 }
```

Can someone help me or navigate, what's wrong?

Comment: Why `td` tags inside your `form` tag... ?

Comment: @Mivaweb I removed some formatting tags because I wanted to shorten the post. But if it is needed, I can post whole block.